Integrate $\int_0^1 \sqrt{9t^4-2t^2+1} dt$
Integrate $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \sqrt{9t^4-2t^2+1} \, \mathrm dt$.
It is from my Maths textbook. The original question was as follows -

Find the perimeter of the loop of the following curve:
$$ay^2 = x^2(a-x).$$

Now, it is known, the length of any curve (say $s$) is given by
$$s =\int \sqrt{1 + (\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx)^2}\, \mathrm dx.$$
Here,
$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{(2a-3x)}{2\sqrt{a(a-x)}}.$$
Now, perimeter will be:
$$s = 2\int_0^a \sqrt{1 + (2a-3x)^2/4a(a-x)} \, \mathrm dx$$
Substitute $x = a \sin^2\theta, \, \mathrm dx = a \sin(2\theta) \mathrm d\theta$
and afterwards put $\cos\theta = t, \, -\sin\theta \mathrm d\theta = \mathrm dt$.
The integrand will be
$$= \int_0^1 \sqrt{ 9t^4 -2t^2 + 1} \mathrm dt.$$
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

This is it .    1.35779593032277

If the text has not covered elliptic integrals, then leave the answer in the form  $\int_0^1 \sqrt{ 9t^4 -2t^2 + 1} \mathrm dt.$

Hint
You made a nice work but the problem is that
$$\int\sqrt{ 9t^4 -2t^2 + 1} \,dt$$ requires elliptic integrals with complex arguments. The formula is rather nasty (have a look here).
I shall not type the result here. Use numerical integration.
Edit
If you want an approximation, since the integrand is minimum at $t=\frac 1 3$, write
$$I=\int_0^{\frac 13}\sqrt{ 9t^4 -2t^2 + 1} \,dt+\int_{\frac 13}^1\sqrt{ 9t^4 -2t^2 + 1} \,dt$$ and use series expansion centered at $t=0$ for the first and at $t=1$ for the second.
Suppose that we use $5$ terms for each series. For the first one, it will be
$$1-t^2+4 t^4+4 t^6-4t^8+O\left(t^{10}\right)$$ and for the second one
$$2 \sqrt{2}+4 \sqrt{2} (t-1)+\frac{5 (t-1)^2}{\sqrt{2}}
-\frac{(t-1)^3}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{9 (t-1)^4}{8
   \sqrt{2}}+O\left((t-1)^5\right)$$
Integrating termwise, the result will be
$$\frac{2012062}{6200145}+\frac{296 \sqrt{2}}{405}=1.35812$$ while, converted to decimals, the exact result is $1.35780$
